# TextBox Contents Add To A MySQL DataBase And then Displayed in PHP/HTML File

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, text

I am using the code below:

```
  <form>
<textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="link"></textarea>
<textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="notes"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I need code to insert it into a MySQL database and then code to display the contents of that MySQL database in a long list of link and notes going like:

link

note

2link

2note

but without the number 2 and in either a PHP or HTML file or both.

How would I accomplish this?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Selecting:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

To get the value, you first have to add two more parameters to your form tag:

method, which is how the values will be passed (google post/get)

and action, which is the page where the form will be submitted to, and processed

Like this:

```
<form method="post" action="path/another_page.php">
```

The, in another_page.php, you can use PHP's $_POST variable to retrieve the values:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (link, notes) VALUES ( {$_POST['link']} , {$_POST['notes']} )";
```

If you want to add the numbers, you can both use an sequential id, or add them programatically, like this:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  ++$i;
  echo $i .") " . $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer, see if it's more specific with your question now